# event isn't defined only in FireFox - defined in Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, firefox

I had a problem where in my function only in FireFox, it was saying that `event` is undefined. However the code worked perfectly fine in Chrome and Safari. The relevant code before the fix is below:

```
function searchOpen(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  searchOverlay.classList.add("show");
  searchOverlayInput.focus();
}

function searchClose() {
  if (event.target.classList.contains("search-overlay__search-bar", "search-suggestion-item", "search-suggestion-item__link")) {
    return false;
  } else {
      searchOverlay.classList.remove("show");
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < navSearch.length; i++) {
  navSearch[i].addEventListener("click", searchOpen);
}

searchCloseButton.addEventListener("click", searchClose);
```

The above code worked in Chrome and Safari perfectly fine, but in firefox, I could open the search unit but if I tried to close it, it threw:

> ReferenceError: event is not defined

So, in `searchClose()` I passed in event, so it was:

```
function searchClose(event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains("search-overlay__search-bar", "search-suggestion-item", "search-suggestion-item__link")) {
    return false;
  } else {
      searchOverlay.classList.remove("show");
  }
}
```

And that fixed it.

But what I don't understand is that `event` is never referenced in that function, I only pass it into the `searchOpen()` - but how come *only* in FireFox it threw a reference error? Why did the old code work on Chrome and Safari?

Comment: because event is not defined

Comment: Hmm...where this is falling apart for me is if event is not defined then howcome Chrome and Safari don't catch that error? And no reference to event in the `searchClose()` function, only `searchOpen()` - so why would `searchClose()` return event undefined when I don't refer to it anywhere in the function?

Comment: too lazy to look it up, but search `window.event` Some browsers support it, others do not.

Comment: You sure it's never referenced? This `if (event.target.classList.contains` in the `searchClose` function sure looks like it's referenced.

Comment: @gforce301 I still don't understand why it broke in FireFox *only*? Is this just one of those "quirks" that nobody can explain?

Comment: Did you do the research mentioned by epascarello? `window` is the global object and some browsers have `window.event` on it. So for the browsers that have it `event` is defined "globaly" and they don't throw the error. Firefox obviously is not one of those browsers.

Comment: @gforce301 oh, ok that makes sense. Couldn't find any concrete info about event being a global variable built into the browser upon researching `window.event` but this is very helpful. Thank you.